# How do I set indent to 2 spaces in js2-mode?

Tags: emacs, js2-mode

I have this at the end of my .emacs:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 2 120 2))
```

It works fine in other modes – whenever I tab, it adds two spaces. But in js2-mode, it adds 4.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set `js2-basic-offset` to 2.

1. `M-x customize-variable`
2. Enter `js2-basic-offset`
3. Set the value to 2

Then `Apply and Save` button in the customize option buffer. This will add an item to set the variable into `.emacs` or `init.el` file.

Comment: I have this set, and in some cases uses 2, but in other cases it uses 4.

Comment: When I do this, anything at two levels of indentation becomes a tab, instead of four spaces. How do I prevent that?

Comment: I think setting `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` will help you.

Comment: Thanks!  But it would sure be nice if every mode in emacs would use the same name to set index or something close with a mode specific prefix.

Answer (score 15):

Little late here, but if you're like me and keep configurations for major modes in separate files, you can add the following line and it works as well.

```
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook (lambda () (setq js2-basic-offset 2)))
```

Answer (score 13):

For me `js2-basic-offset` is an alias to `js-indent-level`, so I had to change the latter to make it work.

Comment: I haven't tried changing `js2-basic-offset` as a user customized variable as the accepted answer suggest, but to change it as a simple `setq` in a `.emacs`, yours should be the answer, because setting `js2-basic-offset` didn't work to me either. Using `setq-default` for `js2-basic-offset` works as well.

Comment: Everything else that was recommended seemed to fail. `js2-indent-level` works fine!

Comment: @Mapsy, if I don't mistake it should be `js-indent-level`, not `js2-indent-level`.